# Laravel email configuration for live server

Tags: php, laravel, email, phpmyadmin

I have installed laravel script on web server but unable to properly configure email settings. I want to use my hosting provider email on laravel script. 
The script sends email when user register or request for verification code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Did you have a *question*?

Comment: Yes. Please tell me how to configure smtp in laravel.  P.S. The script is already configured to send mails when user register or request for verification mail. I only want help to add smtp in it.

Comment: @Manisha Add your code in question Because nobody gives solution like this question.

Answer (score 0):

Find the .env file and edit the following with your smtp information:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=host
MAIL_PORT=port
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```